# Configurable product is not added to cart in catalog page Magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, addtocart, ajax, ajaxaddtocart

I recently created a configurable product, when I select any of the size and color from catalog page then click add to cart button, it will redirect to the cart page.

**Not Added any item in my Cart.**

So any suggestions please?

Comment: Something related to caching or cookie. Can you please try the same on private browser?

Comment: @SukumarGorai i've using Firefox private window, same result.

Comment: Can you disable the ajaxcart extension you are using for testing purpose and try again?

Comment: @SukumarGorai i've disable the ajaxcart extension, same result.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons, the issue is occurring

First [`form_key`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php#L82) is not working when we have tried to cart. Maybe Cookie setting issue or might be some extension going invalid the form key. Please check the all 3rd party extensions.

Second, any exception is happing during add to cart, enable Magento log an d check and those errors.

Comment: No any error in log file.

Comment: Check request goto to https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php#L82  at here

Comment: My problem is the form key, i've using catalog ajax scroll when scrolling a new products appear in the page and when adding it to cart it redirect to cart page and the product not added so i've disable ajax catalog scrolling and it's working perfectly but what is the solution for that?